# Object UNDEFINED Error for existing Dom Objects

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Dom is showing the ***Nodelist[i].properties*** of ***document.querySelectorAll("tr")*** as ***'UNDEFINED'*** eventhough they exist as ***OBJECT's*** and can be accessed and iterated over.
Specifically for *.innerText* ,the node text gets returned as string but still the Dom gives an Undefined error.

Why is the Dom not recognising the object type and its properties?

***CONSOLE:***

```
querySelectorAll("tr") dtype,string,object = object,[object NodeList],NodeList[]  
rowArray[0] = (string),     PurchaseTime    Expiry  Product Temperature Color  
tables1 copy.html:66 rowArray[1] = (string), 1  12-May-2023 13:29:09    18-May-2023 Apple   40  red
tables1 copy.html:66 rowArray[2] = (string), 2  12-May-2023 13:31:08    18-May-2023 Banana  10  black
tables1 copy.html:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')
    at tablesCssAutoWidth (tables1 copy.html:64:27)
```

***Code(+Table)*** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
</head>
<body> 
    <table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>PurchaseTime</th>
      <th>Expiry</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Temperature</th>
      <th>Color</th>
  
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>12-May-2023 13:29:09</td>
      <td>18-May-2023</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>red</td>
 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>12-May-2023 13:31:08</td>
      <td>18-May-2023</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>black</td>
     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
</body>
</html>
<script>
  window.onload = function tablesCssAutoWidth(){


    const tableNodelist_tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
    console.log("querySelectorAll(tr) dtype = %s,%s,%o" ,typeof(tableNodelist_tr),tableNodelist_tr,tableNodelist_tr)

    // const tableNodelist_tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
var row_allArray = []
for (let i = 0; i <= tableNodelist_tr.length; i++) {

    let row_idata = tableNodelist_tr[i]
    row_idata = row_idata.innerText
    let row_idtype = typeof(row_idata)
    console.log("rowArray[%s] = (%s), %s",i,row_idtype,row_idata)

    row_iArray =  row_idata.replace(/\s/g, ",").split(',');
    row_allArray.concat( row_iArray)}


console.log("querySelectorAll(tr)[1].innerText dtype = %s,%s" ,typeof(tableNodelist_tr.innerText[1]),tableNodelist_tr.innerText[1])

console.log("row_allArray= %s",row_allArray)

for (let i = 1; i <= tableNodelist_tr.length; i++) {  

  if(
  parseInt(row_allArray[i][5]) <20 |
  row_iArray[i][6] == "black" ){
  row_iArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";}
  
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Style needs to be rendered based on 'IF' condition cell value (IF is not getting evaluated above  which is the main issue) . nth-child  formatting is based on row numbers  and is not evaluated based on cell value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cannot read properties of undefined` error comes from seems to be an incorrect condition in the `for` loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= tableNodelist_tr.length; i++) {
```

With this code, the iterator will go through `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`, but the `tableNodelist_tr` only has indices up to `2`. This means that the following statement:

```js
let row_idata = tableNodelist_tr[i] // = tableNodelist_tr[3]
```

Evaluates to `undefined`. Thus, the following statement after:

```js
row_idata = row_idata.innerText // = undefined.innerText
```

Tries to read the `innerText` property of `undefined` which is invalid.

The solution is to adjust the condition from *less than or equal to* (`<=`) to *less than* (`<`):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tableNodelist_tr.length; i++) {
```

```js
window.onload = function tablesCssAutoWidth() {
  const tableNodelist_tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
  console.log("querySelectorAll(tr) dtype = %s,%s,%o", typeof(tableNodelist_tr), tableNodelist_tr, tableNodelist_tr)

  // const tableNodelist_tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
  var row_allArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < tableNodelist_tr.length; i++) {

    let row_idata = tableNodelist_tr[i]
    row_idata = row_idata.innerText
    let row_idtype = typeof(row_idata)
    console.log("rowArray[%s] = (%s), %s", i, row_idtype, row_idata)

    row_iArray = row_idata.replace(/\s/g, ",").split(',');
    row_allArray.concat(row_iArray)
  }

  console.log("querySelectorAll(tr)[1].innerText dtype = %s,%s", typeof(tableNodelist_tr.innerText[1]), tableNodelist_tr.innerText[1])

  console.log("row_allArray= %s", row_allArray)

  for (let i = 1; i <= tableNodelist_tr.length; i++) {

    if (
      parseInt(row_allArray[i][5]) < 20 |
      row_iArray[i][6] == "black") {
      row_iArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>PurchaseTime</th>
      <th>Expiry</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Temperature</th>
      <th>Color</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>12-May-2023 13:29:09</td>
      <td>18-May-2023</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>red</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>12-May-2023 13:31:08</td>
      <td>18-May-2023</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>black</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```